What causes the Staging Ground page for an already-approved question to become invisible?
I noticed that for most Staging Ground questions, if I already approved them, the Staging Ground version will become a permanent read-only state, and will still be viewable as the revision when the question was posted, even if the published version on the main site is later deleted or edited. An example is this which I am able to view just fine from within Staging Ground even though I cannot view the question on the main site due to having <10k reputation.
However, I found this on my Staging Ground history, that I had apparently approved and published, but now the Staging Ground version is missing (404 page).
What can cause a question to be retroactively deleted on Staging Ground even after having already been approved and published? What exactly happened to that second question I linked?

You can't see it because the question has been deleted by the author and it requires 10k rep to view deleted posts:

Similarly, this is what it looks like on the main site:

Deletions in the Staging Ground can happen if:

Roomba deletes it for inactivity (SG questions cannot be answered or voted on)

I think this doesn't apply for published questions but I have seen it with questions marked off-topic (I didn't find any Roomba'd questions that weren't marked as off-topic).


The author deletes it
A moderator deletes it
10k+ rep users vote to delete it (question must already be closed for 2 days)
The question gets sufficiently many spam or R/A flags

In total (at the time of writing and including inactive posts), we have

17148 nondeleted questions in the Staging Ground that are published
5466 deleted Staging Ground questions that were published.


I did not know Staging Ground questions could be deleted by their author after they have been published. So I guess the author can delete their main-site question, separately from their Staging Ground question.

Yes; the main-site question is a separately tracked entity that, aside from having a "timeline" that includes a link back, follows all the same rules as a question normally directly created on the main site.

Authors have a delete button below their Staging Ground posts. It seems like they just deleted both posts on their own.

@Abdul Aziz Barkat Are you sure 10k users can delete SG questions? Do you have an example of that happening? Until now, I have only seen that button existing and not displaying an error message if clicked.

@dan1st Well the button is there and I can cast a vote so it should work. Here's an off-topic question I just cast a delete vote on as an experiment.
